# Unique vs non-unique index

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My table holds nearly 40+ million records., with DML.

Would like to know  which one of these Unique or non-unique index would be better option for  implementation. To give better performance.

Environment : Oracle 11g

Comment: It depends on your requirement. and what type of data you have in the column.

Answer (score 22):

If possible, use a unique index. Otherwise, use a non-unique index.

In other words, if you can use a unique index, you should. If there is any reason why duplicate data might need to be recorded, you don't have a choice anyway.

If the index is guaranteed unique, Oracle can perform certain query plan optimisations that are not possible with a non-unique index - for example, if a unique index is used to probe for a particular value, Oracle can stop processing further index blocks as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: i have a table on which two columns are searched for in "and" condition. A combination of these 2 values can't occur again in table, however i haven't given a unique constraint. Will it be better to have a unique, or non-Unique index on them?

Comment: @RachitGupta: the answer is no different whether you have one column or multiple columns in a candidate key.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Does a SQL statement not need to explicitly include an indexed field to be optimized or indexes could be used on non-unique fields. I read that both but which is not required

Comment: @engicode123 Oracle might use any index whether unique or non-unique, and whether the leading columns are referenced or not; the efficiency of the index for serving a particular query is determined at runtime based on the index characteristics and data statistics.

Answer (score -5):

this entirely depends on type of the data in the table if it has data where uniqueness is

high then use B-tree else use Bitmap index.